# Logic about image of a Bilinear transformation.

Tags: complex-analysis, mobius-transformation

I have to find image of $\{z\mid Re(z)\leq 0\}$ under a complex bilinear transformation which maps points $0,-i,\infty$ to $10,5-i5,5+i5$ respectively.

I am thinking like, as all points $0,-i,\infty$ are on imaginary axis and that $10,5-i5,5+i5$ on the circle $|z-5|=5$ in clockwise direction . Now as we walk on  imaginary axis from $0$ to $-i$, the region $\{z\mid Re(z)\leq 0\}$ is to the right  and hence image will be in right hand  if we walk clockwork around circle $|z-5|=5$, so required image is $|z-5|<5$. Am I correct ? Please suggest me and I need proper result regarding this . In Book “Visual Complex analysis” by Needham  at page number $149$, it is given related to this but I am unable to understand. Thank you.

Comment: Yes, that's correct.

Comment: @runway44 thank you ... can I always do the same or looking for zero as mention in Needham book that I unable to understand.

Comment: In the second-to-last sentence of your post, in the phrase "it is given related to this," what do the words "it" and "this" refer to? I don't know what "looking for zero" means in your comment. I don't really understand what your issue is.

Comment: @runway44 sorry for my poor English... I will try to edit it ...